# Is it possible to have Traefik handle multiple certificates/ domains

Tags: traefik

My domain name `jstock.co` DNS, and SSL certificate are handled by Cloudflare.

I have the following `traefik.toml`

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  users = ["admin:xxx"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        CertFile = "/app/cert.pem"
        KeyFile = "/app/key.pem"
```

With the above setup, traefik able to re-route the following traffic to correct docker containers

- `https://notification.jstock.co/info/`
- `https://iex.jstock.co/info/`
- `https://intrinio.jstock.co/info/`
- ...

---

Now, we have purchased another domain name `wenote.me`. Its DNS, and SSL certificate also handled by Cloudflare.

I was wondering, is it possible, to reuse existing Traefik, to handle traffic from `wenote.me`?  If so, what should be `traefik.toml` looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it is being done.

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  users = ["admin:xxx"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        CertFile = "/app/cert.pem"
        KeyFile = "/app/key.pem"
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        CertFile = "/app/wenote.me.cert.pem"
        KeyFile = "/app/wenote.me.key.pem"
```